# HorizontalViewAngle of Camera in Android Device

Tags: android, camera

Are there any android devices that gives HorizontalViewAngle or VerticalViewAngle of camera dynamically?
Most of the devices like HTC inspire, desire etc. gives fixed HVA and VVA.

Answer (score 0):

Angle of view corresponds the angle of view of a particular hardware sensor and is fixed. And hence calls to get the HVA and VVA will give the fixed angles all the time on all the devices.